# Best fit plane using Least Squares Method and mean error

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression

I'm currently using Least Squares Method in order to calculate Best Fit Plane for a given 3 column vectors [X, Y, Z].

I've noticed that consistently I get that the average of the residuals of Z relative to ${Z_{BFP}}$ is zero.

e.g. E($Z_{i}$-${Z_{BFP_i}}$)=0, even though that this method is solving for the plane that minimizes the sum of the squares of the residuals (the vertical (Z) distance) and not for the plane that minimize the sum of the residuals.

I'm trying to understand if this behavior is a byproduct of the Least Squares Method or it is related to the specific distribution of the data I'm testing.

Comment: Could be missing something, but three noncollinear points uniquely determine a plane. That is, the best fit plane will *exactly* fit those three points. You'd need more points that are not coplanar in order to have a nonzero residual.

Comment: The 3 column vectors represent a noisy data that does not perfectly lies on a plane, but only approximately lies on a plane.

Comment: That depends on whether the plane is determined before the three column vectors are generated, or after (logically). So, if, given an already-existing plane, you're asking whether three data points lie on it, the answer would be no. But if, given three non-collinear points, you determine the best fit plane, it will be exact every single time. Three noncollinear data points, noisy or not, *always* determine a plane uniquely.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, though I'm not quite sure I understood you.
I will try to shed some more light on my scenario, hopefully it will clarify so I can get an answer to my question.

I am conducting an experiment, the output of it is a Point Cloud in 3D, that suppose to represent a real plane, though since I'm using a physical device to capture this plane ( 3D camera), I don't get a perfect plane, but rather a point cloud which is distributed around a plane.
See example below:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/36353/versions/1/screenshot.jpg

Comment: The picture to which you linked shows way more than three data points. Are you sure it's just three vectors to which you're fitting a best-fit plane?

Comment: Yes, the scenario shown in the link above is exactly my case.
I have 3 vectors, (X vector, Y vector, Z vector) each vector consists of thousands of points, all vectors are of same length of course, together they represent a Point Cloud of (roughly) a plane, just as can be seen in the link from previous comment.